# How to remove line breaks generated by sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a file called `sms`:

```
gsm versi jadul

29 sender: +62896666666
date:   15/02/14,03:55:12

reboot router
```

when I type in:

```
sed -n '6p' sms > /tmp/result
```

The `/tmp/result` always looks like this:
[image: image1]

Notice the line break there, I want to get rid of the line break on the second line, so the final result will be like this:
[image: image2]

How do I do that?

Comment: Your `sed` statement generates a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

You could trim it off with `tr` like this:

```
sed -n '6p' sms | tr -d '\n' > /tmp/result
```

Comment: I tried that before posting this question, but didn't work, it still has a line break in the result file

Comment: I don't get a newline on OS X with `sed -n '6p' sms > /tmp/result`. Maybe it's your editor or operating system.

Comment: I'm on OpenWrt and my text editor is notepad++ (windows)

Comment: Windows? Maybe (also) a \r, try `tr -d "\r\n"`.

Comment: @Lin try converting your file to unix.....in a shell execute "dos2unix name_of_file"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` instead of `sed`:

```
awk 'NR==6 {printf $0}' sms > result
```

- `NR==6` specifies line number
- `printf $0` prints that line without any `\n`

Comment: You can shorten this this: `awk 'NR==6' sms > result`

Comment: Indeed removing {printf $0} will shorten it..however ...+1 from me

Comment: @Jotne & Xorg - the point about this solution is to not print the ORS, so the `printf` is required, but that doesn't address the real problem the OP has anyway as it's control_Ms in the input file. Aman - Never do `printf $0` - think about what would happen if `$0` contained `%s`. Always use `printf "%s" $0` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your sed command, your input file contains trailing control-Ms. Remove them with `dos2unix` or similar before running sed.

Answer (score 0):

A correct implementation of the POSIX `sed` command does not add such a blank line. `6p` should print the sixth line. I cannot reproduce the issue on, for example, Ubuntu 12 Linux. You have some line ending problem or some such issue.